# Xcode 9 crashing when running split view app on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

After working just fine on both iPhone and iPad for a month, my Xcode 9 app has consistently started crashing causing me the following fatal problem: When I build & run it on an iPhone (simulator or device) Xcode completes loading the app and then crashes too fast for me to copy/paste the error from the debugger. When I run on iPad it works fine leading me to believe this is a result of something related to the split master/detail view.

If I use **either** an exception breakpoint **or** an "all C++ exceptions" it will stop at the AppDelegate class and crash if I hit play. If I use **only** an "all Objective-C exceptions" it will crash as before.

In the debug view hierarchy I get the following errors as well:

```
Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy.
Details:  Log Title: Data source expression execution failure.
Log Details: error evaluating expression “(id) 
[[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGTargetHub") sharedHub] 
performRequestWithRequestInBase64:@"...

Log Method: -[DBGDataSourceConnectionLibViewDebugger 
_executeLLDBExpression:forRequest:onPotentialThread:iteration:]
_block_invoke_2
Method:   -[DBGViewDebugger updateDebugHierarchy]_block_invoke_2
```

I have tested other apps and this issue is unique to the app I am working on. Any ideas or debugging tips for how to proceed? I might just have to redo this whole project again if I can't even find the root cause of this! Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you reported the issue to Apple via bugreport.apple.com ?

Comment: No need thanks to the solution detailed below

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution: Reset Simulator Device**

I managed to resolve the above issue thanks to some serious digging. First, to resolve the instantaneous crash problem, I set a breakpoint at every line in the app delegate. That allowed me to narrow the error to a memory handling problem. From there I started running the code on one of each device available, and realized the crash only occurred on devices I had used earlier in development. Resetting those devices solved the problem.

The core issue here is that when you clean/rebuild your xcode program, it updates the app code on the device, but not necessarily the data model information. So when I changed my data model by including new data and renaming old data it was not properly updated.